# Array Coverage in systemverilog

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog, uvm

I have an array  `en_abist_ov[0:12]`. Each time I sample a covergroup i would like to see if that specific element  `en_abist_ov[i]` is set.
so i would like to create a coverpoint for each element of the array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can have arrays of covergroups in SystemVerilog, eg:

```
covergroup CG with function sample (input bit c);
  option.per_instance = 1;
  coverpoint c;
endgroup 

CG cg [16];
```

You then need to construct them in a loop:

```
bit en_abist_ov[0:12];

initial begin
  foreach (en_abist_ov[i])
    cg[i] = new;
```

And then you can sample each one in another loop, eg:

```
foreach (en_abist_ov[i]) 
    cg[i].sample(en_abist_ov[i]);
```

---

eg:

```
module M;
  
  bit en_abist_ov[0:12];
  
  covergroup CG with function sample (input bit c);
    option.per_instance = 1;
    coverpoint c;
  endgroup 
   
  CG cg [16];

  initial begin
    foreach (en_abist_ov[i])
      cg[i] = new;
    { << {en_abist_ov}} = 13'b1010101010101;
    foreach (en_abist_ov[i]) 
        cg[i].sample(en_abist_ov[i]);     
    { << {en_abist_ov}} = 13'b0;
    foreach (en_abist_ov[i]) 
        cg[i].sample(en_abist_ov[i]);     
    foreach (en_abist_ov[i])
      $display("s[%0h]=%b, coverage cg[%0h].get_inst_coverage= %f", i, en_abist_ov[i], i, cg[i].get_inst_coverage);
    $display("cg[0].get_inst_coverage= %f", cg[0].get_coverage);
  end
  
endmodule
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/LZSi

Comment: it seems not ok with the simulator I m using  ( Xcelium)

Comment: @Mxm89 Yes, it seem like "xmvlog: *E,CGIANS (testbench.sv,11|3): Arrays of covergroup instances are not supported."

Comment: @Mxm89 works with all other simulators in eda playground. check with cadence.

Comment: @Mxm89: I believe that per the SV specification 19.4), you cannot put an array of covergroups in a class, only in module scope.